Export-DbaScript: How can I make it make a directory if it doesn't already exist?
I like to use Export-DbaScript to export to folders that are named C:\TargetFolder\Database\Schema. Often, I don't already have a Database\Schema folder, which will cause Export-DbaScript to fail to write to that folder. Is there any way to make Export-DbaScript create the folder if it doesn't already exist? I'm expecting something like a -Force parameter, but I have not found it in the documentation.
I'm doing
Export-DbaScript `
  -InputObject $_ `
  -NoPrefix `
  -NoClobber `
  -FileName "$($MyLocation)\$($_.Database)\$($_.Name).sql

When the path doesn't exist, I get System.IO.DirectonaryNotFoundExceptions. I'm on version 2.1.18

Export-DbaScript does deal with missing directories, but only for the -Path parameter.
Use:
Export-DbaScript
  -InputObject $_ `
  -NoPrefix `
  -NoClobber `
  -FilePath "$($MyLocation)\$($_.Database)\$($_.Name).sql" `
  -Path "$($MyLocation)\$($_.Database)"


You seem to know PowerShell better than me. Does this behaviour strike you as a bug? Or is it normal to have Path and FileName parameters with different behaviours?

A bit of a bug IMO, it should have combined the two together or just created the directories from -FilePath, rather than needing the full path. You can file an issue on Github https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/blob/master/public/Export-DbaScript.ps1

My thoughts match yours, but I think I'll decline to file the bug. I'm already swamped with open source work. Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have figured this out on my own.
